# how to pass enum as parameter to function in objectivec

Tags: objective-c, enums

The header file looks like:

```
enum RatingsEnum
{
    userRating,
    criticRating,
};

@interface SFMovie : NSObject

- (NSNumber *)getRating:(NSDictionary *)movieDic :(enum RatingsEnum) rating;

@end
```

How can I use this method getRating? I am not sure how to pass the enum. My calling code:

```
- (void) testGetCriticRatingMethod{

    NSMutableDictionary *ratingDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [ratingDictionary setObject:@"Certified Fresh" forKey:@"critics_rating"];
    [ratingDictionary setObject:@"70" forKey:@"critics_score"];
    [ratingDictionary setObject:@"Certified Fresh" forKey:@"audience_rating"];
    [ratingDictionary setObject:@"87" forKey:@"audience_score"];
    SFMovie *movie = [[SFMovie alloc]init];
    enum RatingsEnum ratings;
    NSInteger userRating = [movie getRating:ratingDictionary rating:userRating];
}
```

This produces the following warning:
*No visible @interface for 'SFMovie' declares the selector 'getRating:rating:'*

Can somebody guide me to a good enum tutorial? Thank you all.

Comment: This really doesn't have anything to do with enums. It's just about naming methods in general.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I did not spend enough time debugging before asking the question here :(. I saw the mistake right after putting the question on stackoverflow :(

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Change

```
 - (NSNumber *)getRating:(NSDictionary *)movieDic :(enum RatingsEnum) rating;
```

to

```
 - (NSNumber *)getRatingWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)movieDic ratingEnum:(enum RatingsEnum) ratingEnum;
```

Change

```
 enum RatingsEnum ratings;
 NSInteger userRating = [movie getRating:ratingDictionary rating:userRating];
```

to

```
 enum RatingsEnum ratings = userRating;
 NSNumber *ratingFromUser = [movie getRatingWithDictionary:ratingDictionary ratingEnum:ratings];
```

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with the `enum`, or the type of the parameter at all. Your syntax is simply wrong. The name of the method as declared is `getRating::`. A correct call looks like

```
[movie getRating:ratingDictionary :userRating];
```

Add a label to the second parameter

```
- (NSNumber *)getRating:(NSDictionary *)movieDic ofType:(enum RatingsEnum)rating;
```